# Will Paginate - NoMethodError - undefined method `total_pages' ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I am trying to do pagination (will_paginate gem) on my project model that has many comments (acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem):

```
@root_comments = @project.root_comments.paginate(:per_page => 2, :page => params[:discussions_page])
```

Stack Trace:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `total_pages' for #<Comment::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fa183d77ce8>:
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
  will_paginate (3.0.5) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb:73:in `will_paginate'
  will_paginate (3.0.5) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb:33:in `will_paginate'
```

Any idea why I'm getting an error?

```
<%= will_paginate @root_comments,:param_name => 'discussions_page', renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

Comment: `:param_name => 'discussions_page` is necessary in erb? Not sure..

Comment: @Nithin yes, necessary because I have other stuff I am paginating